# Issue with this conversion error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Edit: I have implemented all the requirements and suggestions other users have recommended.

The objective of my program is to identify the column data types after loading a CSV file (datetime, string, boolean, int, and float). I originally ran this successfully using the same logic by matching different row patterns using regular expressions. This time around, my supervisor wanted me to explore training ML models (Scikit-learn) to do identify the column data types (specifically dates) instead of using regular expressions entirely.

When using ML models (Scikit-learn) it seems that everything is being identified correctly except for dates. It keeps identifying the dates as floats. What I am having trouble understanding is that I used the same logic as I did with regular expressions, and it worked for all the data types except dates.

For my ML model training (I am using pickle, so some variables are loaded into the next file.) The features are ml_list, and the labels are labels. I load in multiple CSV files into Pandas DF's, and run through each row in the DF, extracting 'slash_count', 'dash_count', 'colon_count', 'dot_count', 'digits' and 'letters'. I am going to include a sample of the schema for matching integers, dates, and floats for the ML model below (there are multiple dataframes, this is the general schema):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import re
import pickle

letters = 0
digit = 0
space = 0
slash_count = 0
dash_count = 0
boolean_count = []
digits = 0
labels = []
date_model_count = 0
int_model_count = 0
float_model_count = 0
boolean_model_count = 0
ml_list = []
ml_list_integer = []
labels_integer = []
ml_list_float = []
labels_float = []
ml_list_boolean = []
labels_boolean = []

def analyze(s):
    return [sum(n) for n in zip(*((c.isdigit(), c.isalpha()) for c in s))]
for x in df['Order Date']: #Date ML Model
slash_count = x.count("/")
dash_count = x.count("-")
colon_count = x.count(":")
dot_count = x.count(".")
digits, letters = analyze(x)
ml_list.append([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
date_pattern_models = [[2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
                       [2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6],
                       [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4],
                       [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6],
                       [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3],
                       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
                       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
                       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7],
                       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8],
                       [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 12],
                       [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 11],
                       [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 10],
                       [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 9],
                       [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 12],
                       [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 11],
                       [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 10],
                       [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 9],
                       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 14],
                       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 13],
                       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 12],
                       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 11],
                       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 10],
                       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 14],
                       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 13],
                       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 12],
                       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 11],
                       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 10]]

if ml_list[-1] in date_pattern_models:
    labels = labels + [1]
else:
    labels = labels + [0]
slash_count = 0
dash_count = 0
colon_count = 0
digits = 0
letters = 0

for x in df9["Row ID"]: #Int
    dot_count = x.count(".")
    slash_count = x.count("/")
    colon_count = x.count(":")
    dash_count = x.count("-")
    digits, letters = analyze(x)
    ml_list_integer.append([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
    if slash_count == 0 & colon_count == 0 & dash_count == 0 & letters == 0 & dot_count == 0:
       labels_integer = labels_integer + [1]
    else:
       labels_integer = labels_integer + [0]
    dot_count = 0
    slash_count = 0
    colon_count = 0
    dash_count = 0
    digits = 0
    letters = 0

for x in df9["Sales"]: #Float
    dot_count = x.count(".")
    slash_count = x.count("/")
    colon_count = x.count(":")
    dash_count = x.count("-")
    digits, letters = analyze(x)
    ml_list_float.append([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
    if slash_count == 0 & colon_count == 0 & dash_count == 0 & letters == 0 & dot_count == 1:
        labels_float = labels_float + [1]
    else:
        labels_float = labels_float + [0]
    dot_count = 0
    slash_count = 0
    colon_count = 0
    dash_count = 0
    digits = 0
    letters = 0

p_data = {'ml_list': ml_list,
          "labels": labels,
          "ml_list_float": ml_list_float,
          "labels_float": labels_float,
          "ml_list_integer": ml_list_integer,
          "labels_integer": labels_integer,
          }
with open('p_data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([ml_list, labels, ml_list_integer, labels_integer, ml_list_float, labels_float], f)
```

After loading the pickled variables, I create a definition and use the pickled data to train the models and return the prediction. I then test the model by loading a sample csv into a new dataframe, then I will implement the algorithms as such:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import re

with open('p_data.pickle', 'rb') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'rb')
    ml_list, labels, ml_list_integer, labels_integer, ml_list_float, 
labels_float = pickle.load(f)

# #Training Date Model
date_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
date_clf = date_clf.fit(ml_list, labels)
# #Training Integer Model
integer_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
integer_clf = integer_clf.fit(ml_list_integer, labels_integer)
# #Training Float Model
float_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
float_clf = float_clf.fit(ml_list_float, labels_float)
def date_model(slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, 
dot_count, digits):
     date_model_count = 0
    date_answer = date_clf.predict([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
    return(date_answer)
def int_model(slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits):
    int_model_count = 0
    int_answer = integer_clf.predict([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
    return(int_answer)
def float_model(slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits):
    float_model_count = 0
    float_answer = float_clf.predict([slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits])
    return(float_answer)

df_fin = pd.read_csv("/Users/rohinmahesh/Downloads/TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv", dtype=str)
df_fin = df_fin.reset_index()
del df_fin['index']
lst = list(df_fin.columns.values)
numrows = df_fin.shape[0]
numcols = df_fin.shape[1]
col = 0
row = 0
date_count = []
int_count = []
str_count = []
boolean_count = []
float_count = []
time_count = []
dict = {}
keys = []
vals = []
variable_1 = 0
date_model_count = 0
int_model_count = 0
float_model_count = 0

while col < numcols: 
    int_model_count = 0
    float_model_count = 0
    boolean_model_count = 0
    date_model_count = 0
    del str_count[:]
    del boolean_count[:]
    while row < numrows:
        var2 = str(df_fin.ix[row][col])
        def analyze(s):
            return [sum(n) for n in zip(*((c.isdigit(), c.isalpha()) for c in s))]
        slash_count = var2.count("/")
        dash_count = var2.count("-")
        colon_count = var2.count(":")
        dot_count = var2.count(".")
        digits, letters = analyze(var2)
        date_answer = date_model(slash_count=slash_count, dash_count=dash_count, colon_count=colon_count, letters=letters, dot_count=dot_count, digits=digits)
        if date_answer== 1:
            date_model_count+= 1
        int_answer = int_model(slash_count=slash_count, dash_count=dash_count, colon_count=colon_count, letters=letters, dot_count=dot_count, digits=digits)
        if int_answer==1:
            int_model_count+= 1
        float_answer = float_model(slash_count=slash_count, dash_count=dash_count, colon_count=colon_count, letters=letters, dot_count=dot_count, digits=digits)
        if float_answer==1:
            float_model_count+= 1
        str_pattern = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', var2)
        boolean_pattern = re.findall(r'TRUE|FALSE|True|False|true|false|t|f|T|F', var2)
        str_count = str_count + [str_pattern]
        boolean_count = boolean_count + [boolean_pattern]
        # How to clear out all the empty values in the array
        str_count = [x for x in str_count if x != []]
        boolean_count = [x for x in boolean_count if x != []]
        row = row + 1
    # Changing the column data types
    if int_model_count == len(str_count):
        df_fin[lst[col]] = pd.to_numeric(df_fin[lst[col]], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
    if float_model_count == len(str_count):
        df_fin[lst[col]] = pd.to_numeric(df_fin[lst[col]], errors='coerce', downcast='float')
    if len(boolean_count) == len(str_count):
        df_fin[lst[col]] = df_fin[lst[col]].astype('bool')
    if date_model_count == len(str_count):
        df_fin[lst[col]] = pd.to_datetime(df_fin[lst[col]], errors='coerce')
    # Converting any column that has type object into a string
    df_fin.update(df_fin.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).astype(str))
    col = col + 1
    row = 0

#Creating Key to create dictionary
keys = list(df_fin.columns.values)
print(df_fin.dtypes)
```

Comment: you need to post the relevant code in the question itself

Comment: @Cfreak Unfortunately, I cannot include the code into the question itself, because the code contains too many characters.

Comment: Reduce it to a [mcve] that does fit in the question, then.

Comment: @rmahesh, then we probably won't be able to help you as we need a [mcve].

Comment: This is not a code review site. https://codereview.stackexchange.com is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is not a code review request. Please don't confuse people by making comments that look like referrals to other sites.

Comment: @user2357112 Done.

Comment: @ForceBru I have made the edits, please let me know if it is adequate.

Comment: That's not minimal.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added all my code into this post.

Comment: @user2357112  I'm struggling to make it any more minimal than this. The real question is with the second block of code.